# grails registration page

Tags: grails, view, registration, gsp

I use grails and I have few registration pages.When user enter few textField values, with "Next" link user have to go to the other page....
After user entered all values data have to be saved.

My problem is that I do not know how to take one page's values from another.

What can I use(sessions, setter and getter methods...) to take all entered values in the last page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do it

1) Doing a post back, This will send all your form variables as part of HTTP request and you can then query the params to get the values

2) Grails has got a special artifact which is flash. Once you put anything in flash , its remains till the next request
3) You can use session to retain the values till the session does't expire

Hope that help

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into [Grails Web Flow](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow)